# Separate AdMob banner from application content with border

Tags: android, xml, admob

I read on [this](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6128877) Google support page that it is against policy to have ads overlap application content, and that ads should be separated from the content with a border.

Currently, below is how I'm showing a banner ad in my app. I think this results in a breach of policy, where the ad is overlapping my content (even if the portion of the screen it overlaps is blank).

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentDrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Main content -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragmentDrawerContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <!-- Banner ad -->
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- Navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/fragmentLeftDrawer"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Question:** I'm not very good with xml layouts. How can I fix the layout of `activity_main.xml` to make it look like the recommended layout below? Would I use layout weights, or another method?

Thank you in advance. I appreciate all advice.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a LinearLayout instead of the FrameLayout, with orientation set to vertical, to make content flow one after the other, as opposed to one on top of the other.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentDrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        orientation="vertical">

        <!-- Main content -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragmentDrawerContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="100" />

        <!-- Banner ad -->
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/fragmentLeftDrawer"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Using `0dp` for the layout height and a weight of `100` will tell the LinearLayout to calculate the size of the AdView first, then fill up the remaining space with the RelativeLayout.

(In this particular case, the weight could have been any non-zero value, because we didn't give any weight to the AdView.)

For more information on layout weights, you can checkout Mark Allison's tutorials on his StylingAndroid blog:

- http://blog.stylingandroid.com/layout-weights-part-1/
- http://blog.stylingandroid.com/layout-weights-part-2/